# CakePHP and masking email sender

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am currently using a function called send:

```
    public function send(){


     if ( !empty($this->request->data) ) {
    $email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $email->from(array($this->Auth->user('email') => $this->Auth->user('username')))
    ->to(array('helpdesk@example.com'))
    ->subject($this->request->data['Ticket']['subject'])
    ->send(array($this->request->data['Ticket']['issue']));

    $this->Session->setFlash('Email Sent Successfully', 'default', array('class' => 'message update span9'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

    }
```

to Send emails to our helpdesk and deposit them into their database.  All is working EXCEPT the FROM always shows the username/email address from the configuration options.  It is not masking the email with the users email..  I need this to happen so that we know who is having the support issue.

Does anyone have a suggestion here on what to do?

*Addition

This is an intranet application and thus we have an authenticated GENERIC USER using smtp settings.  This is not spamming, we just want to know which user the Help Desk ticket came from when inserting to the DB.

Comment: you may not send emails from other users email accounts without smtp settings and authorization. you can only send emails from your account (valid emails anyway). put their email in the "reply to" header. that's how its done.

Comment: Mark, could he successfully use `$this->sender('hisemail@hiscompany','His Company')` and still use the user's email information in the from field?

Comment: as I said, the "reply to" is there for this very reason.

Comment: True, but `$this->sender()` is also there if you want to send an email on behalf of a user, right? I think as long as he is "spamming" himself, it would be OK. I think it would be a problem if he was using a user's email address to send a message to a 3rd party. As always, I value your input!

Comment: How would the email servers know if the email owner agreed? the emailing happens in PHP below the surface. there is no "handshake" here. Emails are also used for official correspondence and in a legal context (signing/contracts). It would be very very hurtful for the trust in emails bad if this malpractice would be anything but spam-flagged. Imagine me, sending your boss or other people in your life very disrespectful emails looking like they have been fully authenticated/send by you. not nice, is it?

Comment: but besides that, you might be right. sender() in combination with a foreign from() should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the Config `default` anyway?

If you use `$email = new CakeEmail();`, does the email sent references the Authenticated User email info.

Also, you should always use `$email->sender('support@yourcompany.com', 'Your Company Support');`. This ensures that if there is an issue the problem get redirected to you and not the user, your app is sending an email on his/her behalf.

I have that setup in my account and it works just fine. To Mark's point, it may not be legal (although, that does not seem to be your issue), but I know it is possible as I have currently a system setup that works with whatever email I want. I do not use any Config and also I do not use any SMTP

Comment: it's a very bad form of spamming if you use a foreign from address (sending mails as other users - impersonating them so to speak). such unauthorized emails should and will end up in the spam folder. if not already blocked by providers due to the lack of trust in them. email providers usually do that based on the reversed domain lookup (matching your domain ips). so you could set up email account for each of your users - all using the same `@yourcompany.com` domain (user1@yourcompany.com, user2@...). that would be ok then.

Comment: Mark, I tend to slightly agree with you. However, all I use that for is, when a user accesses my site and wants to send an email to me/contact form, I have their entered email address as $email->from and my email, say support@domain.com as $email->to. I am not using their email to spam other users, I am just sending the contact form THEY filled out to me. If you go to CNN.COM and want to email one of their news article to a friend, CNN does not use their email, they explicitly use the one you entered. Thats the same approach I am taking. I did not think that was SPAM in any way. Thanks!

Comment: in "this specific case" you might not think so, and the owner of the email might not think so. but the email servers still will assume so (how should they know that in this case both participants agree to violate protocol here?). A good contact form always uses the system email address and sets the "reply to" with the sender information. So if you "hit" reply in your email program you are then addressing the right person.

Comment: Using sender() most likely will also validate the message if you use a foreign from() address. this way you can still see that this email has been sent from a third party application. BUT "In all cases, the "From:" field SHOULD NOT contain any mailbox that
   does not belong to the author(s) of the message". Therefore the protocol does not see this as a good practice - see http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html At least I dont think this is meant to leave the "same domain" scope (the examples also point this out).

Comment: Thanks Mark for the comments... I take all this as an opportunity for learning...